# Removing columns from a file

Tags: text-processing

I'm trying to remove columns 75 through 85. The `colrm` command works, but the problem is that it stops whenever it finds an extended ASCII character in the file.

So, my question is this: is there anyway to delete those columns from files that have extended ASCII in them?

Comment: “Extended ASCII” is just confusing terminology for “non-ASCII”. What encoding is the file in? Do you want to remove those columns counting in bytes or characters?

Answer (score 1):

This command will remove columns 75 to 85 (counting bytes) from `input.txt`:

```
cat input.txt | cut -b 75-85 --complement
```

Comment: A side note: formulating your rather short answer as a question brings it straight to Low-quality queue. I suggest you to write answers in affirmative tone. I made an edit to give you an example, you can re-edit your answer if you like.

Comment: The command you submitted works perfectly. Thank you.